# Checkbox for layers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, checkbox, gis

My goal is to have four different groups of markers (which could be three different colors in each group). I need to be able to turn on/off based on checkboxes on the top of the map: Group 1, 2, 3, 4 along with a way to filter those groups by color (Example: Group 1, Group 2, Group 3, Group 4 & Red, Yellow, Green). I originally had this set up for PullDown list; now I am having issues getting any of my checkboxes to respond to these click events. I am not an experienced developer so I apologize in advance if I didn't explain this correctly, any advice is appreciated. Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet  -->    
<html>
  <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="included.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <Title>Web Tool</Title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header"> 
      <h1>jQuery Header</h1>   
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <br>    
    </div>
    <br>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <br>
        <script>
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];  
    var infoWindow;     
    var places = [ 
        ['loc1', 47.364, -92.690, 12, '<h2>place 1</h2>'], //Test RED 
        ['loc2', 43.711, -95.719, 1, '<h2>place 2</h2>'], //Test YLW 
        ['loc3', 44.947, -92.854, 2, '<h2>place 3</h2>'], //Test GRN 
        ['loc4', 45.899, -91.521, 10, '<h2>place 4</h2>'], //Test RED 
        ['loc5', 45.223, -91.127, 5, '<h2>place 5</h2>'], //Test YLW 
        ['loc6', 46.448, -90.166, 2, '<h2>place 6</h2>'], //Test GRN 
        ['loc7', 40.471, -107.580, 3, '<h2>place 7</h2>'], //Test RED 
        ['loc8', 38.208, -104.574, 11, '<h2>place 8</h2>'], //Test YLW 
        ['loc9', 39.623, -104.452, 2, '<h2>place 9</h2>'], //Test GRN 
        ['loc10', 33.186, -101.407, 3, '<h2>place 10</h2>'], //Test RED
        ['loc11', 32.210, -103.262, 9, '<h2>place 11</h2>'], //Test YLW
        ['loc12', 33.991, -103.858, 4, '<h2>place 12</h2>'], //Test GRN
        ['loc13', 47.364, -92.690, 3, '<h2>place 1</h2>'], //Test RED 
        ['loc14', 43.711, -95.719, 1, '<h2>place 2</h2>'], //Test YLW 
        ['loc15', 44.947, -92.854, 6, '<h2>place 3</h2>'], //Test GRN 
        ['loc16', 45.899, -91.521, 3, '<h2>place 4</h2>'], //Test GRN 
        ['loc17', 45.223, -91.127, 8, '<h2>place 5</h2>'], //Test YLW 
        ['loc18', 46.448, -90.166, 2, '<h2>place 6</h2>'], //Test GRN 
        ['loc19', 40.471, -107.580, 0, '<h2>place 7</h2>'], //Test RED 
        ['loc20', 38.208, -104.574, 1, '<h2>place 8</h2>'], //Test GRN
    ];
    //alternate btw 3 different colored markers for this..
    var icons = [
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png',
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-circle.png',
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png',

    ];
    // center map in middle of Nebraska
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.658014, -99.439275);

    //create the map
    function createMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            zoomControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
            }
        });

        //create a global infowindow to show content
        //set a maxwidth of 300 pixel
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            maxWidth: 300,
            map: map
        });
    }

    function initMarkers() {
        for (var i=0; i<places.length; i++) {
            var place=places[i];

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2],place[3]),
                map: map,

                //set icon, category as icons index 
                //outcomment this line if you just want to show the defuult icon
                icon : icons[place[3]],

                //add data from places to the marker
                title : place[0],
                category: place[3],
                content: place[4]
            });

            //add the marker to the markersArray, used to hide/show markers
            markersArray.push(marker);
            //create a click event that shows the infowindow when a marker is clicked
            //the infowindow get latlng and content from the marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setPosition(this.position);
                infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
                infoWindow.open(map);
            });
        }
    }
    //show / hide markers based on category
    //if category is 0, show all markers
    function showMarkersByCategory(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
            if ((category==0) || (markersArray[i].category==category)) {
                markersArray[i].setVisible(true);
            } else {
                markersArray[i].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
    function initialize() {
        createMap();
        initMarkers();

        //init the select box where you show/hide the markers per category
        var checkbox=document.getElementById('checkbox');
        checkbox.onclick = function() {
            var category = this.value;
            showMarkersByCategory(category);
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head> 
    <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:800px;float:left;clear:none;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 20px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">   
            <br>
            <form id="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="0">All Groups&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 1" value="1">Group 1
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 2" value="2">Group 2
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 3" value="3">Group 3
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 4" value="4">Group 4
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 5" value="5">Red
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 6" value="6">Yellow
            <input type="checkbox" name="Group 7" value="7">Green
            </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a value of your form and not a checkbox.

Also, I believe you will be faced with other issues as well moving forward, but this should get your code "working":

```
checkbox.onclick = function() {
    var checkedBoxes = $('#checkbox > input:checkbox:checked');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++){
        var category = checkedBoxes[i].value;
        showMarkersByCategory(category);
    }
}
```

Other issues I see you having is when multiple checkboxes are checked, you will only get the markers from the value of the last checkbox in the loop.

You may want to try this:

```
function showMarkersByCategory(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
        if ((category==0) || (markersArray[i].category==category)) {
            markersArray[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
function initialize() {
    createMap();
    initMarkers();

    //init the select box where you show/hide the markers per category
    var checkbox=document.getElementById('checkbox');
    checkbox.onclick = function() {
        for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
            markersArray[i].setVisible(false);
        }
        var checkedBoxes = $('#checkbox > input:checkbox:checked');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++){
            var category = checkedBoxes[i].value;
            showMarkersByCategory(category);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a "quick fix", the code could be cleaned up but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You mentioned I will have other issues, can you suggest how I can resolve the issues?

Comment: Does anyone know how I can control the color groups? To filter the search component? Also If I can refresh the map and clear the recent selections that would be best. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @BobC the other issues are in regards to when multiple checkboxes are checked.  I submitted code which can help you get around the issue.  To address your other issues is too long for a comment, so please post a new question so it can be answered.  If the answer above I provided is helpful, please mark it as accepted.